# Stored Procedure with multiple REF_CURSORs: CallableStatement.getObject(parameterName) returns null

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I need to invoke following two Oracle procedures using jdbc:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_GetReportGoogleMapData (
p_SubsID number ,     cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
...)

create or replace PROCEDURE PRC_GET_PRFMANA_RPT_DATA (
p_SubsID VARCHAR2,  p_psi varchar2, p_psy number, p_PageSize number,  
p_CurrentPageNo number, p_TotalPageCount  VARCHAR2, p_TotalRecordsCount VARCHAR2,
cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,  cur1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
...
)
```

**Java Client code** using ojdbc7.jar:

```
  private static void namedCall(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    try (CallableStatement prepareCall = connection
            .prepareCall("{call PRC_GET_PRFMANA_RPT_DATA(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}")) {

        prepareCall.registerOutParameter("cur", -10); //oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR
        prepareCall.registerOutParameter("cur1", -10);

        prepareCall.setString("p_SubsID", "1000");
    ...
        prepareCall.setString("p_TotalRecordsCount", "");

        int execute = prepareCall.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(execute);
        try (ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) prepareCall.getObject("cur")) 
         {
            System.out.println("PRC_GET_PRFMANA_RPT_DATA()named:" + resultSet);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not allowed to use Oracle classes directly in my code.

When I tested for **PROC_GetReportGoogleMapData**, prepareCall.getObject("cur") returned a valid ResultSet.

But when I tried to invoke PRC_GET_PRFMANA_RPT_DATA, prepareCall.getObject("cur") returned **null**.

While debugging I found in the later case that inside     oracle.jdbc.driver.**T4CResultSetAccessor**.unmarshalBytes(),

```
int i = (int)this.mare.unmarshalUB4();// line#309
```

i becomes <=0

so, the following inside else is getting executed:

```
this.newstmt[this.lastRowProcessed] = null;
```

as a result,  T4CResultSetAccessor.getCursor(int paramInt) is returning **null**.

**Environment**:

Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation

Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252

OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

NLSRTL  12.1.0.2.0  Production

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition  12.1.0.2.0  64bit Production

PL/SQL  12.1.0.2.0  Production

TNS for Linux:  12.1.0.2.0  Production

Comment: Oracle raises  SQLException: Invalid column type: 2012 against prepareCall.registerOutParameter("cur", java.sql.Types.REF_CURSOR);

Comment: Have you tried using prepareCall.execute() rather than prepareCall.executeUpdate()? I've never called SPs that return multiple ResultSets (cursors) though the Oracle docs says it's possible https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDPJD/addfunc.htm#TDPJD213

Comment: Use Oracle types instead (e.g oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR)

Comment: @dsp_user, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR = -10;  I have also tested execute, but without any difference in result.

Comment: Like I said, I've never had SPs return multiple cursors so I'm not sure.

Comment: @dsp_user, That's fine! But where in your link: have you found information about multiple cursors?

Comment: Your java code looks ok, I've never spotted the problem with multiple out cursors. Check your pl/sql proc. I think the problem is there.

Comment: Just search multiple ResultSet when you open that page.